# Constraining T to a common generic property

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

I have the following:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    IEntityContent Data { get; set; }
}

public interface IEntityContent { }

public interface IThingService<T>
{
    void DoThing(T item);
}

public class BaseEntity<T> : IEntity
    where T : IEntityContent
{
   public abstract T Data { get; set; }
}

public class FooEntity : BaseEntity<FooContent>
{
    public override FooContent Data { get; set; }
}

public class FooContent : IEntityContent
{
    // Some properties
}

public class ThingService<T> : IThingService<T>
    where T : IEntity
{
    public void DoThing(T item)
    {
        Serializer.Instance.Serialize(item.Content);
    }
}
```

The signature of `Serializer.Instance.Serialize` is:

```
string Serialize<T>(T from)
```

But I get the following:

> 'BaseEntity<T>' does not implement interface member 'IEntity.Data'. 'BaseEntity<T>.Data' cannot implement 'IEntity.Data' because it does not have the matching return type of 'IEntityContent'

Why is this? As it stands, I am forced to create a bunch of near-identical strongly-typed implementations of `IThingService` - which is a shedload of duplication - just to specify different type arguments which, as far as I can see, should be generic.

Is this somehow related to a lack of covariance in `BaseEntity`? How can I make `ThingService<T>` work?

Comment: What is the definition of `IComponent`? Interface implementations must exactly match the signature and return type of the interface members.

Comment: @mikez - my mistake - that should have been `IEntity`. Fixed my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply have:

```
public interface IEntity<T>
{
    T Data { get; set; }
}
```

For an implementation of the interface has to match the interface (as you've not declared any contra/covariance), including the return types (hence your error message)

Comment: This would work but would mean I'd have to change the signature of `ThingService` to `Thingservice<T, TContent>`, which I was trying to avoid given that it should be possible to infer `TContent` from `T`. Is there no way around this?

Comment: By a similar token, I would have thought that `Data` is implicitly a `IEntityContent` given the type constraint for `BaseEntity`?

Comment: But you don't decorate it as such on the interface implementation: `public abstract T Data { get; set; }` had that been `public abstract IEntityContent Data { get; set; }` then it should work as well (as your other option) (I'm assuming that `BaseEntity<T>` has some default implementation details that means you don't have to just dispense with that altogether)

Comment: I did try this as well; however it then complains that `FooEntity.Data` doesn't implement `IEntityContent.Data.get` and `IEntityContent.Data.set`. I think I'll have to stick with specifying both type arguments to `ThingService` even though the second is implied by the first.

Comment: Gave up trying to achieve this in the end as it was a massive timesink. Ended up just adding the second type parameter to the service.